# How to install libcurl

Tags: debian, software-installation

I am trying to use libcurl in a c++ program on a Raspberry Pi running GNU/Linux Debian Stretch.

To find all installed curl packages:

> dpkg-query -l *curl* | grep '^.i'

which returns

> curl
>
> libcurl3:armhf
>
> libcurl3-gnutls:arm

Running

> curl-config --cflags

returns that there is no such command. A program with a declaration:

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
```

and compiling and linking with

> g++ -o test test.cpp -lcurl

returns that there is no such "curl/curl.h" file. All the tutorials claim that curl-config is installed with curl. I didn't install curl; it is included in the distribution. Running the command

> curl -I http://www.any_site.com

returns correct data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the package `libcurl-dev` for development. (Or as of 2023, it may be `libcurl4-openssl-dev`.)

From [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libcurl-dev)

> Virtual Package: libcurl-dev
>
> This is a virtual package. See the Debian policy for a definition of
> virtual packages.
>
> Packages providing libcurl-dev
>
> libcurl4-gnutls-dev
>
> development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)
>
> libcurl4-nss-dev
>
> development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS flavour)
>
> libcurl4-openssl-dev
>
> development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)

Comment: What is the difference between these different "flavors" of libcurl? As a `hello_world.c` developer, how would I be impacted if I chose one flavor instead of another? For discussions' sake, say that I am only interested in very simple use of libcurl, e.g. I am expecting to only use `curl_easy_setopt()` and `curl_easy_perform()`.

Comment: @StoneThrow I would advise a new question, and I suspect it to be more the domain of StackOverlow, which is more oriented towards development issues.